# Apply inline style to an element in React from a child element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am still very new to React and I am trying to recreate a navigation bar that was originaly made with HTML, CSS and JS.

I have a `Layout` component and a `Navbar` component. In the `Navbar` component I have a button that when clicked should apply an inline style or a CSS class to the `<main>{children}</main>` element in the `Layout` component.

The `Navbar` element is used inside the `Layout` element, so I am wondering if this is even possible?

layout.js

```js
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql} from "gatsby"
import Navbar from "./navbar"

const Layout = ({ location, title, children }) => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          menuLinks {
            link
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar pages={ data.site.siteMetadata.menuLinks } />
      <main>{children}</main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

navbar.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import styles from "./styling/navbar.module.less"

const Navbar = ( props ) => {

  const [navbarState, setNavbarState] = useState(false);

  let toggleNavbar = () => {
    console.log("Navbar toggle - Activated")
    
    setNavbarState((navbarState) => !navbarState)

  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', windowResized)
    
  return (
    <nav id={"navigation-bar"}>
      <div className={`${styles.navLinks} ${navbarState? styles.navActive:""}`}>
        {props.pages.map((page, index) => (
          <Link key={page.name} className={`${styles.navLink} ${styles.navLinkHoverEffect} ${navbarState? styles.navAnimate:""}`} 
          style={{animationDelay: `${index / 7 + 0.5}s`}} to={page.link}>
              {page.name}
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className={`${styles.burger} ${navbarState? styles.toggle:""}`} onClick={toggleNavbar}>
        <div className={styles.line1}></div>
        <div className={styles.line2}></div>
        <div className={styles.line3}></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible. When you want the child, `Navbar`, to change something in the parent (normally state) you can pass a function down. In `Layout`:

```
const [classes, setClasses] = useState('');

const setClassNames = (classnames) => {
   setClasses(classnames)
}
```

Pass this function down to the child as a prop.

```
<Navbar pages={ data.site.siteMetadata.menuLinks } setClassNames={setClassNames} />
```

When the action occurs on the child, say an `onClick` event then call that function with the classes string you want to set on `main`.

Then in your parent component, `Layout` change the line to:

```
 <main className={classes}>{children}</main>
```

Of note, the way it's currently setup you could just pass the `setClasses` to `Navbar` but I used a new function to just to show a more common scenario when you have to customize anything. Also you should use `useCallback` on the function `setClassNames` in `Layout` if you don't want `Navbar` to re-render every time.

Feel free to leave a comment with questions.